# Change google maps v3 streetview to another div/canvas

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I currently have two divs for google maps v3. One for the map itself and the other for streetview. When someone clicks on an object in the sidebar menu or on a marker, it shows the streetview in the streetview div.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to add a custom control that toggles the streetview between the two divs.

So standard it should be:

```
var streetview = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("streetview"), panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(streetview);
```

and when someone clicks on the control it should be:

```
var streetview = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map"), panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(streetview);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could control the divs itself, instead of messing with the Maps API. You can use container divs and then just swap "#map" and "#streetview" parents, for instance.